# How to solve the incorrect date value error when putting an csv file into MySQL with python?

Tags: python, mysql

I have a table in csv file and I want to import it into a MySQL table. I copy paste a series of data from a website into an excel file and then convert it to csv file.

The columns in my table are like:

```
Date,name,version,link
```

the format of the date is like dd/mm/yy

primarily I tried to load the file into mySQL table but I got this error code 1292:

```
Incorrect date value while the date value is set as DATE
```

I have also tried to put the CSV table to MySQL with python but still have the same error:

```
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1292, "Incorrect date value: 'Date' for column 'Date' at row 1")
```

Do anyone has any idea what should I do?

Comment: You'll probably have to translate the dates from `dd/mm/yy` to `yyyy-mm-dd`.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2238611/1205368) should help.

Comment: "primarily I tried to load the file into mySQL table" HOW? "Does anyone have any idea what should I do?" Yes. Provide us with relevant information.

Answer (score 0):

yyyy/mm/dd  and yyyy-mm-dd both formats will work

Answer (score 0):

Since your format is `dd/mm/yy` so its giving error.
It should be like `yy/mm/dd` or `yymmdd` or `yyyymmdd` or `yy-mm-dd` or may other ways.

so change it from `dd/mm/yy` to `yy/mm/dd`

Read more [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-literals.html)

Answer (score 0):

I scrape a table from a web page and paste it into Excel. Then I save the Excel as csv format. However, Excel csv format contains Unicode characters because the table I scrape has them. So be sure to handle the Unicode before trying to put into your database.