# MySQL: Import data (string) as time using LOAD DATA

Tags: mysql, time, mysql-workbench

I have a dataset (in csv) which contains a column with value like "13.22.00". I would like to guess this is "hh.mm.ss".

How can I convert it to type time (it is string now) like hh:mm:ss?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change string date to MySQL date format at time of import of CSV using MySQL's LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2238611/how-to-change-string-date-to-mysql-date-format-at-time-of-import-of-csv-using-my)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `SET` clause in `LOAD DATA` to transform the input data before putting it into the table. E.g. if the time is in column 2 of the CSV and you want to put the time into the `time` column of the table

```
LOAD DATA INFILE "filename"
(col1, @col2, col3, ...)
SET time = REPLACE(@col2, '.', ':');
```

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate your help!