# MySQL I need to import data from a txt file but in the file i have different datatype

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

MySQL I need to import data from a txt file but in the file I have different datatype.

This is how it looks in workbench:

```
load data local infile 'C:/Users/user/Desktop/visits.txt'

       into table Docs
       character set utf8
       fields terminated by ','
       enclosed by '"'
       ignore 4 lines
       (VisitDate,EntranceHour,FirstName,LastName,DocName,DocLastName,Hospital)
       ;
```

When I proceed I get warnings for VisitDate, in txt is this format 22/04/2005.

Thanks!

Comment: [LOAD DATA INFILE easily convert YYYYMMDD to YYYY-MM-DD?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10102167/load-data-infile-easily-convert-yyyymmdd-to-yyyy-mm-dd)

Comment: @Solarflare I think he dates are in the wrong format.  The year always has to come first AFAIK.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen yes, I know, but I was kinda certain op could figure it out that way on his own with this link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your date data (`22/04/2005`) is not in a format acceptable to MySQL, which is what your warning message is all about.  To get around this, you can use the `SET` statement along with `STR_TO_DATE` to convert your dates into a format which MySQL can handle.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/Users/user/Desktop/visits.txt' INTO TABLE Docs
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
IGNORE 4 LINES
(@var, EntranceHour, FirstName, LastName, DocName, DocLastName, Hospital)
SET VisitDate = STR_TO_DATE(@var, '%d/%m/%Y')
```

See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2238611/how-to-change-string-date-to-mysql-date-format-at-time-of-import-of-csv-using-my) for more information.